# xcodebuild command failing on codesign but logs show incorrect profile uuid being used

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild, codesign

I try to run this:

```
xcodebuild -scheme "MobileRenderStress.iOS" -destination "generic/platform=iOS" archive -archivePath /Applications/buildAgent/work/builds/MobileRenderStress-iOS.xcarchive
```

Which results in this:

```
<Many lines of irrelevant log that ends with...>

Signing Identity:     "iPhone Developer: DK (RYQ82Z5555)"
Provisioning Profile: "iOSTeam Provisioning Profile: com.company.*"
                  (0b51596e-46c1-456a-a7bc-911858ad275a)

/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign A72FD8239B6355AE7DECC865F1A13226450F76C --entitlements /Users/builder/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Technology-ajtzoltdytdzndgefjzzhzhiufjx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MobileRenderStress.iOS/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/MobileRenderStress.iOS.build/Debug-iphoneos/MobileRenderStress.iOS.build/MobileRenderStress.iOS.app.xcent /Users/builder/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Technology-ajtzoltdytdzndgefjzzhzhiufjx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MobileRenderStress.iOS/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/MobileRenderStress.iOS.app
/Users/builder/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Technology-ajtzoltdytdzndgefjzzhzhiufjx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MobileRenderStress.iOS/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/MobileRenderStress.iOS.app: User interaction is not allowed.
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1

** ARCHIVE FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CodeSign /Users/builder/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Technology-ajtzoltdytdzndgefjzzhzhiufjx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MobileRenderStress.iOS/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/MobileRenderStress.iOS.app
(1 failure)
```

I've been running xcodebuild commands both for building and archiving (in this example I am archiving) but I am receiving codesign errors. The confusion comes especially from the fact that the logs indicate exactly which provisioning profile ID it's trying to use (and successfully finds) but the command line for "codesign" is indicating a different ID. Even if I specify the profile in the xcodebuild command, it still ends up trying to use this different, non-existent ID in the codesign line.

Has anyone come across this before and know where that ID is even coming from? I grep'd my entire project and it's nowhere to be found. It's kinda creepy, really.

Important Notes:
When I update the provisioning profile to get the ID to change, the xcodebuild command STILL tries to use the A72 ID at the codesign line. It's really frustrating!

I do see the part of the log that indicates "User interaction is not allowed." Although this doesn't relate to the issue, do know that it's using the --force command in the line which should bypass that error and also the provisioning profile's signing keys are all fully permissive, which is the other workaround for that kind of issue.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The issue is caused by "User interaction is not allowed." this is because it needs a code signing prompt to be accepted which cannot happen from command line until the keychain has been unlocked.

security unlock-keychain -p YOUR_PASSWORD ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain

Also you might want to do it directly in xcode and check it works on the machine.

Comment: That did it! I had everything unlocked and accessible via the keychain access app and my CI app was able to run it all fine but apparently when you go in and try to build manually it requires this completely other way of unlocking the keychain. Weird, but solved my issue. Thanks!

Comment: This worked. I was so stupid to not think of this.